# Use a GPL package in a proprietary licensed software

Tags: ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

if I need to include nodes from a GPL licensed package (e.g. ar_pose) in my application's launch file, can my software have a proprietary license and be commercialized? I'm not linking ar_pose to my own code, I'm just subscribing to its published topics. And if I make some changes to ar_pose, I would just have to publish ar_pose with my modifications, right?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43061/use-a-gpl-package-in-a-proprietary-licensed-software/) by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IANAL, but from my understanding it's not that simple and seems to be pretty open for interpretation (which is why I try to stay away from GPL code as much as possible).

The official FAQ is incredibly vague:
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem

The two programs have to remain well separated for one to use a GPL license and one to use a proprietary one.  From my understanding this is why connecting to a GPL web server from a proprietary browser is ok (they are distinctly separate programs and the communications between them is common and generic).  I don't think however you can write a wrapper for a GPL library that just translates the function calls into TCP messages and communicate with it from a proprietary program.  They've essentially become one system at that point even though they don't actually link against one another.  I'm not sure where ROS falls on that spectrum.

There was another good discussion on the topic here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/12313/using-gpl-licensed-packages-in-a-commercial-product/
and a good, but equally vague/consult your lawyer for a final answer explanation here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/public-license-explained/

---

Originally posted by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) with karma: 395 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-05**:
Given the thread you linked, it sound to me like a "it depends on why the node is there".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IANAL, but I think normally these issues need to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis, and it's always better play on the safe side. It's also important to remember that if there's a chance that someone will take the time to sue you for violating copyright, it also means they should care enough to answer any licensing questions you may have.

I imagine ar_pose's license restrictions come from ARToolKit itself, and on their [license page](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/license.html), they summarize the licensing terms by saying:

> i.e. your software incorporating or linking to ARToolKit must also be open-source software, licensed under the GPL.

I think the above means that you cannot sell a product that uses the GPL-licensed ARToolKit, or at very least that they might pursue litigation if you do. However, there's good news, because they also have professional and commercial licenses:

> In response to demand from toolkit users, the holders of the copyright on much of the ARToolKit version 1.0 - 2.x code have elected to make this code and other substantially advanced ARToolKit and AR code available under proprietary licenses for professional and commercial use by persons for whom the GPL license is not ideal. These license arrangements are managed by [ARToolworks](https://www.artoolworks.com/), Inc., Seattle, WA, USA. A variety of license types are available at reasonable cost. Please contact ARToolworks, Inc. directly for information on products, license terms, and pricing.

If ARToolKit is the only GPL restriction in that package, then I would suggest:

1. Contact the maintainers of the CCNY ROS packages to privately release a version of their ROS interfaces under a BSD or commercial license.
2. Contact [ARToolworks](https://www.artoolworks.com/) to negotiate a commercial license.

If there are other GPL components, then I would suggest looking for similar solutions.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a direct answer to your question, but a possible improvement and workaround.

I have used both `ar_pose` (based on `ar_toolkit`) and [`ar_track_alvar`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_track_alvar) based on [`alvar`](http://virtual.vtt.fi/virtual/proj2/multimedia/index.html) for a project. In my experience the latter one is far better than the former in any terms. Porting your code to use `ar_track_alvar` will likely take about a couple of hours. The stability, robustness and pose estimation accuracy of `alvar` library is not the only benefit you'll earn.  The ROS driver is BSD licensed and the original library is LGPL* which will make it more appropriate to be used in a commercial product.

- [Main difference between GPL & LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License#Differences_from_the_GPL)

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on 2012-09-06**:
Thanks Mani, that seems to solve my problem!

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-09-09**:
You are welcome. I am glad that helped.